# What's the best way to create a vertical button menu in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, button, dart

Total noob here.

I'm making an app menu in Android Studio, using Flutter/dart as my code base. I need to make a series of horizontal buttons laid out in a vertical column.

The button design is essentially an outline button. White button but with a grey outline.

Would it be best to put these buttons in a ListView and have OutLineButtons as the buttons OR have them in a column and the children of that column be rows with the buttons inside?

Appreciate the advice.

[An image i pulled from google to illustrate the layout of what i'm looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ej38C.jpg)

Comment: Can you share any image for your actual requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to the Flutter world.

You can use the `Column` class to do that. [[Here is the doc]](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html)

Inside that `Column` You can add more widget as many as you want.
Example:

```
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
  //Your first menu widget
  //Your second menu widget
  //Your third menu widget
  ],
)
```

You can read the docs or look for tutorials for more information. Happy creating